# How can I make DataGridView.Rows.DividerHeight work?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have tried to make a simple sudoku Interface using dataGridView. The problem is that I can't get `DividerHeight` to work. The code below is able to change the width of the vertical divider, but not the horizontal divider:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataTable sudokuTable; 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sudokuTable = getTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = sudokuTable;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){                        
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = 25;
        }

        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DividerWidth = 5; //Working
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].DividerWidth = 5; //Working
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].DividerHeight = 5; //Not working
        dataGridView1.Rows[5].DividerHeight = 5; //Not working

    }


    private static DataTable getTable()
    {
        DataTable newDataTable = new DataTable();


        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            newDataTable.Columns.Add("c" + i+1, typeof(int));                       
        }

        newDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        newDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        newDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        newDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        newDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        newDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        newDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        newDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        newDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

        return newDataTable;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    } 
}
```

Is there some Properties I have to change to make it work?

I have found a link suggesting dividerHeight is not implemented:

http://www.visualwebgui.com/Developers/Forums/tabid/364/forumid/68/threadid/68506/scope/posts/Default.aspx

Is that true?

(I am using Visual Studio Community 2013 and Net Framework 4.5)

Comment: Your code works fine. I have no problems to display the dividers. What  problem do you have? Note that you ought to add the divider thickness to the rows and columns the dividers sit in: `dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = 25 + ((i+1)%3 == 0 ? 5:0);`

Comment: I haven't gotten to the bottom of it all, but it looks like a timing problem..

Comment: I'm sorry. I was not aware I could do that. I am very grateful for your answer.

Comment: Yes, the [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) points are one of the driving forces here. Do take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) there!! It will help you get some more points & [privileges.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). With 10 you can post images, 15 you can vote up, with 20 you can enter chat and with 50 you can comment everwhere..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works just fine. With a few extra touches it looks like this:

[image]

This is basically your code, applied to a normal DataGridView freshly dropped to the form..:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

    sudokuTable = getTable();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = sudokuTable;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = 25 + ((i+1)%3 == 0 ? 5:0);
    }

    dataGridView1.Columns[2].DividerWidth = 5;
    dataGridView1.Columns[5].DividerWidth = 5; 
    dataGridView1.Rows[2].DividerHeight = 5; 
    dataGridView1.Rows[5].DividerHeight = 5; 

    dataGridView1.Rows[2].Height += 5;
    dataGridView1.Rows[5].Height += 5; 

    dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

    dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView1[0, 0].Selected = false;
}
```

No changes at all to the `getTable` function..

**Update:** I was able to reproduce your problem. My `DataGridView` is on a `TabPage` which was not selected on startup. By calling the button click code **before** selecting the Tab I saw your error; when I put in a line to select the Tab **first** it worked again.. Looks like a problem/**bug** the DGV has with its layout **when it isn't visible** ..

Note: It **never** works when you call it in the **constructor**! That is too soon. `Form_Load` is fine, though..

As a temporary **workaround**, you can move the code to a Start `Button`. (Having a Start button is probably a good idea anyway, for the next round..)

Comment: Thanks. Did what you suggested and moved the code into an button_click Method and i worked! :-D

Comment: Can you tell me: Is the DataGridView visible at startup? Mine was in a tab and it worked fine after I selected the page it was on before filling it..

Comment: Everything was wisible except the horizontal dividers

Comment: So, according to my last tests, moving the code to the Form_Load may also have helped. That was the first thing I did, but as my dgv was not visible then it didn't work. Should work for you..

Comment: That's really interesting.  Without binding works fine in the constructor, but not binding.  But moving it to `Form_Load` works with binding?  I've seen something like this before when checking auto-sized column widths in the constructor - they're always 100 (not actually auto-sized until the form is visible).

Comment: Side note and perhaps a bit OCD: I'd make the following change in the for-loop, just so the last column's width is correct: `dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = 25 + ((i+1)%3 == 0 && i != 8 ? 5:0);`  Again, great find though - confirmed to work in `Form_Load`, you got my +1.

Comment: Yes, thanks, either that or add them in the top and left spot as well; also making the '5' dynamic would be better. But the real queston remains: Can we insert a call to something to make it work in the constructor..?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps a hack, but in the constructor after `InitializeComponent()` and before `sudokuTable = getTable()` just call `this.Visible = true`.  Like you pointed out, the code in the constructor didn't work when it wasn't visible, but this allows it to work.

Comment: No, does't work for me. Actually it was not invisible, just siting on a tabpage that was not selected.

Comment: Ah, I didn't try it with a tabpage.  Without that it works though.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: As TaW discovered, the OP code works fine when moved from the form constructor to `Form_Load`.  See [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30390641/3773066) for details.  I am leaving this answer purely for future reference and as a *secondary* option.

---

<strike>I believe it has something to do with the `DataSource` binding.  For emphasis: I took your code (which also did not work on the row dividers for me) and decided to test something else - due to your comment:</strike>

> suggesting dividerHeight is not implemented

I tested the following, confident it is implemented:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
dataGridView1.Rows[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

The column was successfully colored, but the row remained unchanged.  This led me to question if it was the binding, as I've seen binding cause some weird issues before with styling, accessibility, etc.  Indeed, binding the `DataSource` to other things (like a `List` of custom row objects) also failed.

The above styling changes to rows as well as binding "failed" because the `Form`, and subsequently the `DataGridView`, was not yet visible.  By default, the visibility and bindings are not changed/handled behind the scenes until *after* the constructor has run it's course.

---

Therefore, I took your general idea, TaW's idea for correcting the widths [and heights], and removed the `DataSource` - replacing it with manual filling of the `DataGridView`. The following result worked to accomplish your described desired output:

```
private List<int> dividers = new List<int>() { 2, 5 };
private int pad = 5;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeDataGridView();
}

private void InitializeDataGridView()
{
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.HeaderText = "c" + (i + 1);
        column.Width = 25 + (dividers.Contains(i) ? pad : 0);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
        row.Height = row.Height + (dividers.Contains(i) ? pad : 0);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells)
        {
            cell.Value = cell.ColumnIndex;
        }
    }

    foreach (int div in dividers)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[div].DividerWidth = pad;
        dataGridView1.Rows[div].DividerHeight = pad;
    }
}
```